# Is it correct to use "all" in negative sentences?

Tags: pronouns

Is it true that these sentences are not good?

> All people don't like it.
>
> All the people in that town don't like it.

I've read that "all" shouldn't be used in negative sentences, it should be "none of" instead.

Do you agree?

Comment: I don't like that rule at all.

Comment: _All people dislike it_ would be clearer. _All people don't like it_ could be misinterpreted as meaning _Not all people like it (though some do)_.

Comment: Both example sentences sound incorrect to me. I would mark them wrong in student writing and expect the student to use "none of the people" or "nobody" or some such expression with "no". The rule is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

"All the people disapprove," is perfectly acceptable English, whether formal or conversational colloquial English. It is just as valid as, "None of the people approve," and even more forcefully stated!

The rule you state is arbitrary and artificial.